# Setting anchorPoint and position in a UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation

I have 1 `UIView` added to a `UIStackView` via Interface Builder (for demo's sake). I need to transform this subview at its origin, so I'm setting `layer.anchorPoint` and `layer.position` to `CGPoint(0, 0)`. When the view appears, the layer is moved to it's new `anchorPoint`, but at its original position of `CGPoint(0.5, 0.5).` It's as if I haven't set `layer.position` at all.

In contrast, I tried adding the same subview to another `UIView` without the stack view, and it readjusted as expected. Here is the result of *not* setting the subview's `anchorPoint` and `layer.position`:

```
let background = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 265, height: 55))
background.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = background

let stackView = UIStackView(frame: background.bounds)
background.addSubview(stackView)

let subview = UIView()
subview.backgroundColor = .red
stackView.addArrangedSubview(subview)
```

[image]

Now, when I set the `anchorPoint` and `position` before adding the subview to the stack view, only the `anchorPoint` is respected:

```
// same
let background = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 265, height: 55))
background.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = background

// same
let stackView = UIStackView(frame: background.bounds)
background.addSubview(stackView)

let subview = UIView()
subview.backgroundColor = .red
subview.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) // added
subview.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) // added
stackView.addArrangedSubview(subview)

print(subview.layer.position) // (132.5, 27.5)
```

[image]

I'd expect this to look the same as the first image.

Are there implicit `UIStackView` constraints that override the subview layer's `position`? IRL I'm using Interface Builder with Auto Layout (which I don't *think* should matter since Auto Layout has been transform-friendly since iOS 8), and resetting `position` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is still unreliable, because the subview's `frame` and `position` are all correct until `viewDidAppear` is called, at which point  `subview` is stubbornly repositioned as stackView sees fit.

**How can I set a view's `anchorPoint` and `layer.position` in a `UIStackView`?**

Answer (score 0):

The anchorPoint is work as it for because default is center (0.5,0.5),
set (0,0) mean shift half relative to position.
If you want to change the position of inner view, as UIStack will adjust the position automatically fill it up as it designed for, so change of position no effect on the view  
 Alternatively, you can change the position by use the transform:

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 100, y: 100)
```

or added to exiting transform (default is a no transform matrix)

```
subview.transform = subview.transform.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 100)
```

above code mean it shift the position (100,100)

you also can rotate it by (say 50 degree to left)

```
subview.transform = subview.transform.rotated(by: 50)
```

or enlarge it :

```
subview.transform = subview.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.2)
```